# Triangle puzzle

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

Can you guess the pattern? Fill in the blank for the last triangle[image: 4 triangles, each with a number at each corner and a number in the center. First triangle: {2,2,5,8}, where 8 is in the center. The other triangles: {7,5,2,9}, {3,2,1,1}, {3,7,4,?}]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I think the answer is 5, because 3*4-7=5